# ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop

Tags: system-installation

I plan to install ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop in my old PC.

Following are my current system details,

```
1. Processor - Intel® Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.06GHz × 2 
2. Memory - 937.8 MiB
3. Graphics - VESA: 6330
4. Disk - 156.5 GB
5. OS type - 32-bit
```

Please advise whether I can successfully install ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop in my current system?

Comment: Consider editing your question to make it more specific.  You'll get better input if the users see titles of their interest or experise.  Since this is an Ubuntu site, making the title Ubuntu relates to most of the questions.  More specific would be`Ununtu 16.04 on an old PC` or  `Minumum requirements for Ubuntu 16.04`.   This could help others with a similar question.  Look at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirement **-Official-**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).  You don't have enough ram for Ubuntu 16.04 recommended requirement.

Comment: I suggest you to go with Lubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to install it. But with 1GiB of memory, it's not gonna be fast. I would look at some alternative variants, such as [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net), as they have desktop environments with lower requirements.

Note that you can switch between them after installation, by installing the meta package `lubuntu-desktop` and `xubuntu-desktop`, using `sudo apt-get install <packagename>`.

I'd also suggest getting more memory. A gigabyte or two extra will improve things significantly, and can likely be had for free or cheaply locally, as it's an old computer.

Answer (score 0):

For checking Linux cpu support any x86 CPU will work including 32bit.

Even modern full featured Linux only require about 10GBs of storage.

You will not be able to play almost any 3d games on this computer as it has no 3d acceleration.

Aside from that the first bottleneck will probably be your HDD. Opening applications will be slow but once loaded they will run smoothly.

You actually have sufficient RAM for more basic tasks certainly for minimal multitasking on Linux. But if you're a more aggressive multitasker you'll likely end up swapping to disk.

You will probably hit bottlenecks with the speed of applications before problems with your RAM however when it comes to each application.